# How to add temperature sensor to Mustool soldering iron?

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, soldering, temperature

I have [Mustool Soldering iron](https://www.banggood.com/Mustool-MT223-60W-Adjustable-Temperature-Electric-Soldering-Iron-with-5pcs-Solder-Tips-p-1077119.html?rmmds=myorder&stayold=1&cur_warehouse=CN). It works fantastically however I just want to know the current temperature of it digitally.

Can someone please guide me to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Screw that and get a real soldering iron.

Comment: Rule one:  never buy a soldering iron when the seller says it can be used to weld...

Comment: Agree with Olin, get a real temperature-controlled station like a Weller WES51 or a Hakko FX888D. If you are really cash strapped and can't afford $150 for a good iron (we were all students once), consider one of the myriad Hakko 936 clones available from EBay and AliExpress. The better-known knockoffs are sold by Aoyue, Atten, and Yihua, and can be had for as little as $20 (although I would spend at least $50 for a half-decent clone).

Comment: Well, thanks for the advise guys. However, since it is working right now and isn't giving me any trouble, I would like to stick with it for the time being. However, it would be nice to monitor the temperature in real time which will give me 2 benefits. 1: I will know when my soldering iron is ready. 2: if it is over heating or under heating i.e. not working as it should so then I can look for new soldering iron.

Comment: @PeterK Another affordable entry-level iron these days is the TS100. Can be had for about $60.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T do this!!!! You are handling live voltage that can be deadly!

A possible way to do it is to:

1. Add a switch (relay, MOSFET, TRIAC) that breaks the circuit, power to the heating element.
2. When the circuit is powerless then it's possible to measure the resistance in the heating element.
3. The meassured value is then converted in a A/D converter to a digital value.
4. Programmatically you can now make a table that translate measured resistance to temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I want to be able to check it continuously while I am working with it i.e. soldering iron is turned on and it is heating.
It will be like those soldering station however I will be using lcd panel for just displaying the temperature.

Comment: you are turning it off during a couple of mSeconds.

Comment: @MujtabaAli You really want to dis advice that may save your life or that of some unfortunate who has to use your soldering iron ...

Answer (score 0):

The most practical is is to attach a thermocouple to the tip or the heater/tip sleeve. Then you can just use a cheap thermocouple meter , also from Banggood.

Of course you will have a big box and extra wire hanging off you iron - which is why anyone who seriously wanted this would start with a soldering station.

BTW, you simply should not be using a 2 wire iron to solder anything electronic. The tip is not earthed, and will leak a high voltage into your IC's damaging them.